# Is android debug build device specific?

Tags: android

Can we Bluetooth the apk on the device (that is installed by USB debugging) to another device and use?

(assume the other device has the minimum API etc.)

Comment: do u want to transfer apk to another device ? via bluetooth ??

Comment: You can install it on any device that has unknown sources set to allow.  There is no magic way to just send it merely by being installed on one device to another via bluetooth-  you actually have to transfer the original apk file onto the target device.

Comment: @GabeSechan yp, im asking whether that apk is an apk that works on any device or is it built based on the specs of the particular device that was connected to the computer at the moment of building & thus would not work if transferred to a different device? (since it is specifically catered to work on the first device)

Comment: It will work on any device, with very few restrictions (if you use any .so files, you need a .so of the appropriate architecture.  The device must be of an appropriate SDK version of Android-  at least your minSDK.  If you have any require-feature tags in your manifest, the device must have the required feature).  But there is no restriction to things like model, manufacturer, screen, size etc.